# What does "May his name and his memory be annihilated" really imply?

Tags: curse, memory

It is said that the worst Jewish curse is *Yemach shemo vezichro* -- May his name and his memory be annihilated.

But the vast majority of people, Jewish or not, are not remembered.  They do not leave enough of a footprint on earth to be remembered much beyond a generation or two.  So what, exactly, does not deserving the curse imply in terms of being remembered?

Comment: Cf. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14910

Comment: @Maurice You understand the Roshei Teivot, correct? This was censored out of the Talmud about 1000 years ago.

Comment: There's a suggestion [here](https://stips.co.il/ask/13202061/%D7%9E%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%93%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A7-%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9-%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%97-%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95-%D7%95%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%95) that it's a curse on his progeny as well.

Answer (score 2):

As the Rambam says in the 8th chapter of  הלכות תשובה that after the Evil Ones get punished for all their sins, their souls are destroyed and do not live on for Olam Haba - this cutting off from Eternity is the worst type of punishment possible.

I think that's what we mean when we say  *Yemach shemo vezichro* -- May his name and his memory be annihilated.

> א הַטוֹבָה הַצְּפוּנָה לַצַּדִּיקִים הִיא חַיֵּי הָעוֹלָם הַבָּא וְהִיא הַחַיִּים שֶׁאֵין מָוֶת עִמָּהֶן וְהַטּוֹבָה שֶׁאֵין עִמָּהּ רָעָה. הוּא שֶׁכָּתוּב בַּתּוֹרָה (דברים כב-ז) 'לְמַעַן יִיטַב לָךְ וְהַאֲרַכְתָּ יָמִים'. מִפִּי הַשְּׁמוּעָה לָמְדוּ לְמַעַן יִיטַב לָךְ לְעוֹלָם שֶׁכֻּלּוֹ טוֹב וְהַאֲרַכְתָּ יָמִים לְעוֹלָם שֶׁכֻּלּוֹ אָרֹךְ. וְזֶה הוּא הָעוֹלָם הַבָּא. שְׂכַר הַצַּדִּיקִים הוּא שֶׁיִּזְכּוּ  לְנֹעַם זֶה וְיִהְיוּ בְּטוֹבָה זוֹ. וּפִרְעוֹן הָרְשָׁעִים הוּא שֶׁלֹּא יִזְכּוּ לְחַיִּים אֵלּוּ אֶלָּא יִכָּרְתוּ וְיָמוּתוּ. וְכָל מִי שֶׁאֵינוֹ זוֹכֶה לְחַיִּים אֵלּוּ הוּא הַמֵּת  שֶׁאֵינוֹ חַי לָעוֹלָם אֶלָּא נִכְרַת בְּרִשְׁעוֹ וְאָבֵד כִּבְהֵמָה. וְזֶהוּ כָּרֵת הַכְּתוּבָה בַּתּוֹרָה שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (במדבר טו-לא) 'הִכָּרֵת תִּכָּרֵת הַנֶּפֶשׁ הַהִיא'. מִפִּי הַשְּׁמוּעָה לָמְדוּ הִכָּרֵת בָּעוֹלָם הַזֶּה תִּכָּרֵת לָעוֹלָם הַבָּא. כְּלוֹמַר שֶׁאוֹתָהּ הַנֶּפֶשׁ שֶׁפֵּרְשָׁה מִן הַגּוּף בָּעוֹלָם הַזֶּה אֵינָהּ זוֹכָה לְחַיֵּי הָעוֹלָם הַבָּא אֶלָּא גַּם מִן הָעוֹלָם הַבָּא נִכְרֶתֶת:‏

> ה  הַנְּקָמָה שֶׁאֵין נְקָמָה גְּדוֹלָה מִמֶּנָּה שֶׁתִּכָּרֵת הַנֶּפֶשׁ וְלֹא תִּזְכֶּה לְאוֹתָן הַחַיִּים שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (במדבר טו-לא) 'הִכָּרֵת תִּכָּרֵת הַנֶּפֶשׁ הַהִיא עֲוֹנָהּ בָּהּ'. וְזֶה הָאֲבַדּוֹן הוּא שֶׁקּוֹרִין אוֹתוֹ הַנְּבִיאִים דֶּרֶךְ מָשָׁל בְּאֵר שַׁחַת וַאֲבַדּוֹן וְתָפְתֶּה וַעֲלוּקָה וְכָל לְשׁוֹן כְּלָיָה וְהַשְׁחָתָה קוֹרְאִין לוֹ לְפִי שֶׁהִיא הַכְּלָיָה שֶׁאֵין אַחֲרֶיהָ תְּקוּמָה וְהַהֶפְסֵד שֶׁאֵינוֹ חוֹזֵר לְעוֹלָם:‏

Comment: So the remembrance in question is not remembrance by future generations, but admittance in the World to Come?  If so, why is this not stated clearly?

Comment: Good question - I think it's based on Amalek that we are commanded to wipe out all mention of them, yet we have a yearly "Amalek-Shabbat".